# Does Universe have an overall Entropy?

Tags: entropy, universe

I am just curious to know whether Physicists have given any measurable Entropy to the Universe? If yes then please tell me whether its value is increasing or decreasing overall?

Comment: Partially yes it answers the question... but is the Entropy increasing or decreasing? It seems it is increasing because the Universe is expanding.

Comment: see [2nd law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics). If we assume that the universe is an isolated system (which is reasonable), then this law should hold